# Mobile first hamburger menu doesn't work on the mobile version of the website but it does while scaling down

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem that i'm having involves the hamburger menu not responding on my mobile. However it does work when i scale down my window size of my browser to a mobile sizes window. It seems like something is going wrong but i cant figure out why. Note that i cant use too much classes or ID's since this is a school project.

**This is my current code**

```
 <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="images/spotify.svg" alt="Logo van spotify">
        </a>

        <!-- Gebruik span voor hamburgers bars -->
        <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()" class="toggle-button">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </a>
        <div id="active" class="navbar-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="premium.html">Premium</a></li>
                <li><a href="premium.html">Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="premium.html">Downloaden</a></li>
                <li><a href="premium.html">Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="premium.html">Uitloggen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>`
```

**JS code**

```
`function myFunction () {
  document.getElementById("active").classList.toggle("show")
}`
```

**What ive tried:**

I tried to apply other JS but it broke my code mostly one JS seemed to work however

```
`function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("active");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

This code seemed to work on desktop and on my mobile. However it made my navbar links completely dissapear. And i couldnt figure out why precisely.
I quite a novice with this so any help would be appreciated.

My github is: https://github.com/Koayz/Spotify-Bryan-van-de-Pol
And my website is online too: https://mbdehaan.nl/bryan/spotify/

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />` line in your header?

Comment: its in my <head> </head> like this :  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Seems to work fine

Comment: I changed it to what u have and for some reason it works kind of? but still doesn't when i open the website on mobile

Comment: works fine on my iphone x safari browser, even tho the hamburger is a bit small for tapping

Comment: I see, it must be chrome related then i think using your part of the code for some reason fixed 80% of the problem

Answer (score 0):

The hamburger menu is working for me on Samsung Mobile Browser but not on Chrome Mobile Browser, which suggests that you probably have a CSS rule in there somewhere which is not cross-compatible. I'll dig into your git a little more.

---

I think the problem is that you are using empty spans to simulate the hamburger menu. On firefox web browser, you can click anywhere on the 'toggle-button' `<a>` tag and it will trigger the menu. On chrome web browser, if you click on the spans themselves nothing happens. I think on the mobile version the spans are the only thing being clicked on.

I'd suggest replacing the hamburger spans with an actual `<svg>` element (you can find plenty of royalty free ones online) and attach the function to that, or attach the function to each of the spans as well as the container.

---

By default, the nav elements will enter the regular flow of the document because you haven't specified a position. A simple way to fix it would be to specifiy the height of the navbar at say 50px, then set the position of navbar-links to `absolute` and give it a `margin-top` of 50px. You will want to unset this property for the larger screen view.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed the nav pushes the content down too. Is this fixable too? So it positions itself an layer above the content

Comment: Thank you for trying. Ive tried using a fontawesome icon, but the icon becomes inresponsive and i cant even open the menu then

Comment: I tried what u said, but the black background seems to dissapear, the navbar itself already has position:relative

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise the nav-bar was inside a header tag. Add position `absolute`,  and width `100%` to the header directly, don't add anything to navbar-links.

Comment: Been playing around with this for a while now and realised you will have to add position absolute, width and height 100% to the body as well so that header has a positioned element to size to. I was getting weird borders otherwise. Hope this works out for you.